# Error-Attempt by method 'X.set_DbConnection(System.Data.Common.DbConnection)' to access method 'Y.get_Settings()' failed

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, console-application

I created a console app and use EntityFramework 6.2 (for connection with MS SQL), MySql.Data 8.0.11 and MySql.Data.Entity 6.10.7 (for connection with MySQL).

In this application I want to create a job like an SQL job but I don't want to use quertz.net. I have error:

> "Attempt by method 'MySql.Data.Entity.EFMySqlCommand.set_DbConnection(System.Data.Common.DbConnection)' to access method 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.get_Settings()' failed."

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`MySql.Data.Entity` 6.10.7 isn't compatible with `MySql.Data` 8.0.11.

Oracle [renamed the package](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?3,661134) to [`MySql.Data.EntityFramework`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data.EntityFramework/) for v8.x. You need to uninstall `MySql.Data.Entity` and install `MySql.Data.EntityFramework`.

Comment: How (or where) can I see these incompatibilites? In my project I have: MySql.Data" version="8.0.13" , MySql.Data.Entity" version="6.10.8" ,MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore" version="8.0.13"  and MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" version="8.0.13". Need to uninstall too?

Comment: @Neumann uninstall "MySql.Data.Entity version=6.10.8". All the MySql.Data packages need to be at the same major version, i.e., 8.0.

Comment: I did the uninstall of MySql.Data.Entity 6.10.8 and seems works best. But now I received an error from providers configuration : didnt find System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory. How can I change the ef provider configuration?

Answer (score 0):

They broth thanks, you saved my life. I have lost more than 5 hour trying to figure out what was happening. guys don't forget to put on your database Context.

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySql.Data.EntityFramework.MySqlEFConfiguration))]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error but with "MySql.Data.EntityFramework" already referenced.
My Problem was at the config file. I had to change this:
[image]

To:

[image]