# Cannot update-database from package console during migration

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I am using below the versions for my project.

```
.Net framework 4.5.1,
MySQl.Data 6.9.12,
MySQl.Data.Entity 6.9.9,
MySQl.Data.EntityFramework 8.0.13.
```

While trying to migrate from MS SQL to MY-Sql, and updating database in package console, I am getting the following error.

```
Target database is: '******' (DataSource: localhost, Provider: MySql.Data.MySqlClient, Origin: Configuration).
Applying explicit migrations: [202102130615311_MstoMySql].
Applying explicit migration: 202102130615311_MstoMySql.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator.Generate(CreateTableOperation op)
   at MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator.Generate(IEnumerable`1 migrationOperations, String providerManifestToken)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteOperations(String migrationId, VersionedModel targetModel, IEnumerable`1 operations, IEnumerable`1 systemOperations, Boolean downgrading, Boolean auto)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ApplyMigration(DbMigration migration, DbMigration lastMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.ApplyMigration(DbMigration migration, DbMigration lastMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Design.Executor.Update.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Design.Executor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Comment: have you run the add-migration before?

Comment: Yes, I did that.

Comment: You can't use `MySql.Data.EntityFramework` 8.0.13 with `MySql.Data` 6.9.12: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50222387/23633. This may not be the cause of your problem, but they're not compatible libraries.