# Two different database access in .Net Framework 4.5.2 and Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

As mentioned, I have to configure two database which are MSSQL and MYSQL. For MSSQL case, it works but now I have to add new database (MySQL) but face this question below

```
The type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConfiguration' does not inherit from 'System.Data.Entity.DbConfiguration'. 
Entity Framework code-based configuration classes must inherit from 'System.Data.Entity.DbConfiguration'.
```

For my app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Buffers" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.3.0" newVersion="4.0.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="MySql.Data" publicKeyToken="c5687fc88969c44d" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-8.0.26.0" newVersion="8.0.26.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"></remove>
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=8.0.26.0" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You probably need the assemblies: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html

Comment: @GHDevOps I think I have add the assemblies but still throw this error.

Comment: Where's your dbConfiguration in the web.config? You have to tell EF what configuration to use.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this XML:

```xml
<provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
```

It appears that you may have installed the `MySql.Data.Entity.EF6` NuGet package. That package is no longer supported and is not compatible with `MySql.Data` 8.0.26.

Uninstall it, and install [`MySql.Data.EntityFramework`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data.EntityFramework/) instead.

(Or if you installed `MySql.Data.Entity`, then note that it is also not compatible, as per my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50222387/23633). Again, uninstall and replace with `MySql.Data.EntityFramework`.)