# MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices.GetDbProviderManifestToken to access method MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.get_Settings() failed

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, mysql-connector, .net-4.8, mysql.data

To Upgrade 
**Database:** MySql Version 5.5.62 to 8.0.28 
**.NET Framework:** Version 4.5 to 4.8 
**Entity Framework:** Version 5.0.0 to 6.4.4

I followed the steps:

1. Uninstall and remove all existing mySQL dll of my project
2. Uninstall Existing MySql Server
3. Download the MySql Installer version of 8.0.28 and Install MySql Server
4. Install .NET Connector - 8.0.28 
   DLL's:

   ```
    C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net 8.0.28\Assemblies\v4.8\mysql.data.entity.EF6.dll
    C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net 8.0.28\Assemblies\v4.8\MySql.Data.dll 
    C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net 8.0.28\Assemblies\v4.5.2\MySql.Data.EntityFramework.dll
   ```
5. Change the Target Framework for the Project to .NET Framework 4.8
6. Install MySql.Data - 8.0.28.0 (NuGet Package Manager)
7. Install MySql.Data.EntityFramework - 8.0.28.0 (NuGet Package Manager)
8. Install MySql.Data.Entities - 6.8.3.0
   (*It's not MySql.Data.Entity but MySql.Data.Entities. **[MySql.Data.Entity](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data.Entity/)** has been deprecated as it is legacy and is no longer maintained. According to this [**Answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50216643/error-attempt-by-method-x-set-dbconnectionsystem-data-common-dbconnection-to), need to Uninstall MySql.Data.Entity But My project doesn't contain it because of done step 1*)
9. Install [**Entity Framework**](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework) - 6.4.4 (Upgraded from 5.0.0)
10. Install mysql-for-visualstudio-1.2.8 (Using VS2022)
11. In Global.asax.cs

    *using MySql.Data.Entity;*

In Application_Start()

```
DbConfiguration.SetConfiguration(new MySqlEFConfiguration());
```

12. In Database Context

    *using MySql.Data.Entity;*

    ```
    [DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration))]
    public partial class my_systemContext : DbContext
    {
        static my_systemContext()
        {
            DbConfiguration.SetConfiguration(new MySqlEFConfiguration());
            Database.SetInitializer<my_systemContext>(null);
        }

        public my_systemContext() 
            : base("Name=my_systemContext")
        {

        }
    }
    ```
13. Package Config:

> ```
>   <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.4.4" targetFramework="net48" />
>   <package id="MySql.Data" version="8.0.28" targetFramework="net48" />
>   <package id="MySql.Data.Entities" version="6.8.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
>   <package id="MySql.Data.EntityFramework" version="8.0.28" targetFramework="net48" />
> ```

14. In Web.Config

=> Config Section:

```
<configSections>
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>
```

=> System Data and EntityFramework

```
<system.data>
        <DbProviderFactories>
            <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
            <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=8.0.28, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
        </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
    <entityFramework codeConfigurationType="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6">
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlConnectionFactory, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
        <providers>
            <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
        </providers>
    </entityFramework>
```

=> Connection String and Run Time dependentAssembly

```
<connectionStrings>
        <remove name="my_systemContext" />
        <add name="my_systemContext" connectionString="server=localhost;User Id=root;password=MyPassword;Persist Security Info=True;database=my_system;Convert Zero Datetime=True" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>

<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="MySql.Data" publicKeyToken="c5687fc88969c44d" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-8.0.28.0" newVersion="8.0.28.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>

        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
```

But now application is able to log on by using ASP.NET membership but can't process the LINQ query. Here I am getting the following error:

Attempt by method **

> `'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices.GetDbProviderManifestToken(System.Data.Common.DbConnection)' to access method 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.get_Settings()' failed.`

**

Note: Firstly I tried for latest version 8.0.31. But same problem I found. What I have missed for completing the task or is there any issue of incompatible version? Do I have to downgrade?
Need your help to fix up.

Comment: Side note: remove the assembly bindings. There shouldn't be any reference to old versions.

Comment: Nothing changed when I commented EntityFramework assembly bindings. But when I commented the MySql.Data. I got error before Application_Start() 
`'Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies.`

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I solved the issue.
Just modified the provider tag in web.config

```
<!--<provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />-->

 <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.EntityFramework, Version=8.0.28.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"/>
```